# Why the <form:hidden> value is set as empty?

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, jsp, jsp-fragments

On my default page, I have a hidden fields to set custody details. I've checked the HTML source and the values are coming as empty.

- I tried to check if the controller itself is sending `null` data. But, the data is sent by the controller as expected.
- I tried to debug JSP, input tag is showing the same values correctly whereas, Spring's form tag is showing the values as empty.
- No `BindingResult` errors

  **Object properties with all the required getters and setters**:

```
public class MakeSwitchForm implements Serializable {
    private Custody custody;
    private List<Custody> custodyList;
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping
public String defaultView(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestHeader(name = "Accept-Language") String locale)
        throws ServletException, IOException, PropertyValueNotFoundException, NoSuchMessageException  {
MakeSwitchForm form = new MakeSwitchForm();
List<Custody> custodyList = null;
custodyList = filterUserRightCustodies(redCustody, custodyList);// fetches custody list
form.setCustodyList(custodyList);
model.addAttribute("makeSwitchForm", form);
```

**JSTL**

```
<form:form id="makeSwitchForm" name="makeSwitchForm" modelAttribute="makeSwitchForm" action="${actionUrl}/makeSwitch" method="post" class="opux-g-container">
<%@ include file="subscriptionSection.jspf"%>
```

**subscriptionSection.jspf**

```
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${fn:length(makeSwitchForm.custodyList) == 1}">
        <input type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}" />" id="custodyNumber_0" />
         <form:hidden path="custody.custodyNumber" value="${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}" />
```

**HTML source**

```
<input type="hidden" value="0007832348" id="custodyNumber_0">  
<input id="custody.custodyNumber" name="custody.custodyNumber" value="" type="hidden">
```

Can someone please help me understand why the `<form:hidden>` value is set as empty.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [`<form:hidden>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-view/mvc-jsp.html#mvc-view-jsp-formtaglib-hiddeninputtag) tag has a `path` attribute to access an object's property. It is evaluated from the form's model object mentioned in the [`Model::modelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#addAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)).

So, you have to put `makeSwitchForm` to the `Model` in the controller:

```
model.addAttribute("makeSwitchForm", form);
```

Now, you can access the property `custodyList[0].custodyNumber` like in previous EL expression but using a [`<c:set>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) tag:

```html
<c:set target="${makeSwitchForm.custody}" property="custodyNumber" value="${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}" />
<form:hidden path="custody.custodyNumber" />
```

Comment: Updated path to use with value attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I missed to mention that my controller already has `model.addAttribute("makeSwitchForm", form);`. And still the issue persists.

Comment: I also tried to pass the custodyList value as a model attribute `model.addAttribute("custodyList", custodyList);` in the controller and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Here are few more things that I tried. Instead of `<form:hidden path="custody.custodyNumber" value="${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}" />` I tried to hard code the custodyNumber value as `<form:hidden path="custody.custodyNumber" value="0007832348" />` to check if the issue is with rendering the value of 
 `${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}` . But, even with the hard coded value, it is coming as empty in html source `<input id="custody.custodyNumber" name="custody.custodyNumber" value="" type="hidden">` .I am not sure, if I should just bypass the Spring's form tag

Comment: Yeah, someone had suggested it, but before I'd try to set the name attribute before/after the path. Second, render a value in the tag body.

Comment: Okk, Will try that. I also tried this approach to the set the properties:           `<c:set target="${makeSwitchForm.custody}" property="custodyNumber" value="${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}" />`  `<form:hidden path="custody.custodyNumber" id="custodyNumber_0" />` But, this is breaking the page.

Comment: Well actually, `<c:set target="${makeSwitchForm.custody}"property="custodyNumber" value="${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}" />` worked and is fetching the values correctly. Maybe, there was some temporary issue before.

Comment: Yes, the `value` is a dynamic attribute of `form:hidden` tag and it is overriten by the tag after processing `path` attribute. You can initialize `castody.custodyNumber` either in JSP or in controller. This property has a bidirectional binding using `path` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to set the values as below, it worked fine:

```
<c:set target="${makeSwitchForm.custody}"property="custodyNumber" value="${makeSwitchForm.custodyList[0].custodyNumber}" /><form:hidden path="custody.custodyNumber" id="custodyNumber_0" />
```

**HTML Source**

```
<input id="custodyNumber_0" name="custody.custodyNumber" type="hidden" value="0007832348">
```

It's still a mystery why the [form:hidden](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-view/mvc-jsp.html#mvc-view-jsp-formtaglib-hiddeninputtag) tag is not able to set the values within. But for now, I think this works.